# Attaching DLL to managed process doesn't work

Tags: c++, debugging, dll, process, visual-studio-2017

I have a C++ DLL project (x86) that I need to debug. 
This DLL is consumed by an exe.

I can easily attach the DLL project in VS2017 to a native exe (x86).
When I set breakpoints in the C++ DLL project in VS2017, these break points are hit.
This is the normal, desired behaviour.

Now I have attached the C++ DLL project to a .NET exe (compiled as x86). 
Break points are not hit, and I don't have any idea why that doesn't work like with a native exe.

I have unchecked the option "Use Application Framework", but that didn't change anything.

I have also tried the option "Enable native code debugging" without any success.
Also, I have tried to attach it to a Debug version of the NET exe and to a Release version of the NET exe.

I can see that VS2017 attaches to the correct process as when I close the NET exe, VS2017 goes out of debugging mode.

However, breakpoints are not hit.

Is there anything special that I have to take care of?

Comment: I guess you need to enable debugging of native code.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thank you, but that doesn't change anything.

Comment: Then debug from the DLL side.  Load the DLL project and have the .Net app as the executable to run.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yes, that is what I'm doing anyways: I start the NET.exe project, then I open the C++ DLL project in VS2017 and click "Debug" -> "Attach to process".

Comment: No, don't attach.  Load the DLL project, change the executable to run to the Net executable in the debug configuration of the DLL.  Also, look at the console output carefully and check if the DLL is being loaded and that symbols have been loaded.

Comment: I don't really understand this. My DLL can not run the exe. Or what do you mean, please?

Comment: Yes it can run the executable.  Go to your DLL properties settings.  You see that there is a "Debugging option"?  That is meant for you to add the executable to debug.  That can be the full path of *any* executable you desire, but hopefully the one you claim you need to debug.  The exe will run, thus no attachment is necessary.  The issue now is what I mentioned previously -- is the DLL being loaded the one you expect to be loaded?  Look at the output console when the app runs.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I'm strung out, I need to resume this at a later point of time.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I have edited my post to clarify what I need to do. I'm not sure if that was clear: I need to debug what's going on inside the DLL when it's being called by the exe.

Comment: Right, and the way it can be done is to load the DLL project.  Right click on the project name in the Solution explorer and choose Properties.  In there, you will see the Debugging option and executable to debug.  In there, you put the name of the .Net application.  Did you do that, or are you just assuming it doesn't do what you think it should do?  Then F5 -- You will magically see your app start -- that's what the "Debugging" option is for within the DLL project.  If it didn't make sense, why would such an option exist for a DLL project?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, the managed .exe has not loaded the native DLL. Or it has loaded an incorrect build of the DLL, not the one that you’re debugging.

To troubleshoot, add `__debugbreak();` call in your native code. That kind of breakpoint is very unlikely to be ignored, unless you mess with structural exception handling. Windows will show you a message offering to attach a debugger, you can choose existing instance of visual studio. Once attached, “Modules” window will show you exactly which build of the native DLL it loaded.

The best way to solve that permanently is add two projects in a single visual studio solution, setup dependency, and ensure the DLL output location is where the EXE looks for the library. I do it all the time in VS2017, with native code debugging enabled I can set my breakpoints in either managed or native code, which helps a lot debugging the interop.

Comment: Thank you, I need to test this out with a fresh brain tomorrow.

Comment: I have experienced something really strange and convinient:
I compiled the DLL as debug x86 and then just started my exe. When an exception was thrown, the DLL .cpp file in which the error occured opened up automatically in Visual Studio.

Comment: @tmighty I think you have not just started, but pressed F5 = start with debugger. When you do that, `__debugbreak` intrinsic works just like a normal breakpoint in the code. The difference is that `__debugbreak()` traps to debugger even when it was not already attached. Also will just crash an app on a PC without a debugger installed, i.e. make sure to not use it in your release builds.